# Adaptive card in teams not workig - REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I created a bot (`nodejs` server) for teams - through bot framework.

I'm trying to send adaptive card that I created through: [adaptive cards designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/)

and I get error :

```
{"code":"BadArgument","message":"ContentType of an attachment is not set"}
```

The request body :

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "from": {
    "id": "xxxxxx"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "id": "xxxxxx"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": "xxxxx"
  },
  "replyToId": "xxxxx",
  "text": "some text",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "type": "AdaptiveCard",
      "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
      "version": "1.2",
      "body": [
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "some text"
        },
        {
          "type": "Input.Date",
          "separator": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**I would appreciate help**

Comment: 'Shalom' Hodaya Shalom :-). How are you attaching/sending the card exactly? Have you had a look at the [BotBuilder sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/07.using-adaptive-cards/bots/adaptiveCardsBot.js#L39) for this?

Comment: I am currently using the REST API ׁׁ (I'll check the bot builder). You can see in question the body I am sending (the card is in attachments).

I'd love to know why the error appears in the REST API

Comment: Which REST Api are you using? MS Graph, or Bot Framework itself? If Bot Framework, definitely use the provided libraries rather. If you're going the REST approach, it might be because you're trying to send a Proactive message though, rather than a response to a user - is that right?

Comment: bot framework itself, and yes - i send proactive message, why it is matter? the text meesages send fine, and also cards like hero cards ...

Comment: ok, I figured that, just wanted to confirm. It's slightly different if you're just replying to a message, versus sending pro-active, but either way the Bot Framework provides classes to make it much easier rather than direct REST calls. An editor here on the site didn't like that my original answer had a question in it, so I'll repost it without the question (mah la'sot?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding attachments you'll want to set the `contentType` and `content` properties of the attachment object.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#attachment-object

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "from": {
        "id": "xxxxxx"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "id": "xxxxxx"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "id": "xxxxx"
    },
    "replyToId": "xxxxx",
    "text": "some text",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "content": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                "version": "1.2",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "some text"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Input.Date",
                        "separator": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments above, this is a pro-active message, but using the Bot Framework libraries are a much better approach than trying to call the bot endpoints directly (I wondered if, by "REST", you meant the Bot Framework endpoint or the Graph Api, but in either case the Bot Framework is easier to work with for proactive messages).

Please see specifically [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/07.using-adaptive-cards/bots/adaptiveCardsBot.js#L39) for how to do this in Node.