# The clientId parameter is required - botbuilder

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am building a bot in teams.

I am trying to use npm botbuilder to post messages back to a user in Teams from the server [nodejs].

I was able to receive and send messages with the REST API - but because I was having a [problem sending adaptive cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62016804/adaptive-card-in-teams-not-workig-rest-api/62022287#62022287)  I am trying to use botbuilder.

Here are some parts of the code:

```
 const botbuilder = require('botbuilder'),
    {MicrosoftAppCredentials} = require('botframework-connector');

async function sendDataToClient(msg,turnContext) {
    try {
        MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(turnContext.serviceUrl); 
        await turnContext.sendActivity({text: msg.txt});
    }
    catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
};
```

When the function sendDataToClient is run, I get the following error:

> The clientId parameter is required.

What am I missing?

**EDIT-1**

Code to create the turn context:

```
const adapter = new botbuilder.BotFrameworkAdapter(
            params.appId,
            params.secret
        );


 const context = new botbuilder.TurnContext(adapter, {
            id: params.activityId,
            from: {id: params.uniqueId},
            serviceUrl: params.serviceUrl,
            conversation: {id: params.conversationId},
            recipient: {id: params.senderId}
        });
```

Comment: Are you setting the Microsoft App Id and App Password anywhere? If not, that might be what it's asking for

Comment: Yes, I set it in the adapter & after I saw the error I try to set it also in MicrosoftAppCredentials

Comment: did you have a look at the pro-active sample, at https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages/bots/proactiveBot.js ?

Comment: I'ts also very important to know - you need to HAVE a bot in order to send a pro-active message, but once you have the bot created, and connected to the user, you can actually SEND a message from another application, like an Azure Function or AWS Lamba, for example. It needs to use the same credentials (App Id, etc.) and needs to get certain "conversation" data, which you can get when the user first connects to your bot, but like I said it can be a standalone application.

Comment: All the examples I have seen send activity right after they receive a message. Due to constraints I work with a post method - when I receive a message from the user I send a status 200, and only after that I process the message and post back a reply.
At this point, I have the activity id, conversation id and all the other necessary parameters, so I create TurnContext - take a look at the update I added.

Comment: yes that's what I mean - you don't need to "send activity right after receive" - that's just the sample. What is "params.uniqueId"? I think your "from" should actually be the characters "28:" plus your params.appId, so e.g. {id: "28:" + params.appId }

Comment: Yes. this is the form parameter

Comment: I don't understand - is params.uniquid == params.appId?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow. Yes, params.uniquid = "28:" + appId

Comment: Have you tried actually using the sample in the link I gave earlier on? In particular, look at how it users adapter.continueConversation, at https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages/index.js#L71